# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS IN MULTISITE NETWORK DASHBOARD

Tags: multisite

when i try to open my multisite network dashboard from this:-

> http://domain.com/wp/wp-admin/network/

it's gives me this statment:-

> This page isn’t working
>   domain.com redirected you too many times.
>   Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**[Update]** see the link to resovle above issue:-   [Redirect loop (only for multisite network admin)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175728/redirect-loop-only-for-multisite-network-admin)

Comment: its eaither an htaccess issue or a problem with your DB.  How did you install your WPMS?

Comment: @Aurovrata when i creating WPMS this issue occured, but before all that i changed my site url and home url directly from DB.

Comment: how did u change the home/site url from the DB?

Comment: @Aurovrata  see this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL    on this section Changing the URL directly in the database

Comment: please read through my answer below, did u follow step 2?  is this a fresh installation of WordPress or you copied the db from your local machine?

Comment: @Aurovrata yes i already did that and i install my WPMS from scratch, after my modified the site dashboard worked but when i try to enter network dashboard above issue happened if i clear?

Comment: ok, then did you copy the [htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network?#Enabling_the_Network) file to the server?

Comment: @Aurovrata yes i did,see content of it below 

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]`

Comment: the last thing I can think of is that you have not set the correct site_url/home_url, since you have installed your wpms in a sub-folder.  I will post another solution below

Comment: @Aurovrata i just add this sub folder "wp" to it !

Comment: check my edited answer below, you have to make sure your siteurl/home fields are set properly.  currently from your htaccess it looks like you are trying to do the 2nd option in my answer below.

Comment: sorry ignore, just deleted my previous comment, ignore that.  Your htaccess looks fine, did u actually check the db siteurl/home field values?

Comment: sorry, don't remove, that was my mistake!  Please check your siteurl/home fields in your db

Comment: Yes i checked and i  sure from it

Comment: what are the values?

Comment: Looks like this siteurl = http://domain.com/wp home = http:/domain.com/wp

Answer (score 3):

If you [install your WordPress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network?) (wpms) from scratch on the server this issue should not arise.  However, if you have installed your wpms on a local machine first and then moved/copied the entire installation including the database to your server, then you have to ensure that,

1. you modify the domain in your database.  I am not aware of any plugins that handle wpms installation till date.  However, I use the [Interconnect/it search and replace db tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/).  You need to search for 'localhost/folder' and replace with 'your-domain.com'. The best results is to ensure that you have a similar setup on the localhost as the server.  If you are looking to setup wpms with subdomains, I suggest you create the child sites on the server after successful installation, and export/import  pages/posts for the local machine to the server.
2. you also need to change the wp-config.php wpms settings,

   `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
   define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/local-folder/');`

   to

   `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'your-domain.com');
   define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/'); //or a sub-folder name is not a root installation.`

keep in mind that a lot of things can go wrong with such a procedure, and therefore it is always much simpler to install your wpms from scratch on the server and export/import content from one local to server.

[EDIT] In case you have created a fresh installation, then the likely issue is that you have either a problem with your [htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network?#Enabling_the_Network) file or with the site_url/home_url [settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL).

If you have misconfigured your site_rule/home_url in your dashboard then you need to change it directly in your database.  Follow these [instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database), and assuming from your question that you have installed your WordPress files in the sub-folder `/wp`, make sure that,

1. If you want to access your site with: `domain.com` and your dashboard with `domain.com/wp-admin`, then

`siteurl = http://domain.com
home = http:/domain.com/wp`

2. If you want to access your site with `domain.com/wp` and your dashboard with `domain.com/wp/wp-admin` then,

`siteurl = http://domain.com/wp
home = http:/domain.com/wp`

[EDIT 2]  One more possible reason is the browser caching.  301 redirects are cached by the browser, so clear your cache.  You can inspect what kind of redirection your browser is experiencing by looking at the request trace on the [network tab of the inspector console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor).  This can give you a clue as to where the redirection is being applied.

Comment: yes i changed according to step 2, but this not my issue -> the problem with network dashboard viewing

Comment: do you get the same error when you view domain.com/wp/wp-admin?  Are you able to see the front end domain.com/wp?

Comment: no  error ocurred just on domain.com/wp/wp-admin/network/ , yes i mention this eariler

Comment: you did mention earlier, but you didn't say that it was working with the rest of the dashboard!  that rules out a lot of possibilities.  Did you clear your browser cache?  This can be a reason as 301 redirects are cached!  what type of redirection are you getting when you inspect your request trace on the network tab of your inspector console?

Comment: yes i cleared my browser cach eariler, it's document type

Comment: what is it redirecting to and which code?

Comment: where i can find this?

Comment: 4 comments up or in last edit of my answer.

Comment: yes i see that but i can't find what you asked for ? can please showing your ask by images

Comment: follow the link in the answer, there are screenshots available

Comment: thanks alot for your all answers, Luckily i found the solution in this page:-   https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175728/redirect-loop-only-for-multisite-network-admin

Answer (score 0):

This answer is specific to WordPress Multisite instances set up with Bitnami: .htaccess files may not work as expected. Instead, when I follow these instructions I found on Bitnami docs: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress-multisite/administration/use-directories/ my problem was solved.